# FullCalendar: resize event not working in month view

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I'm working on a Angular 10 project. I am using fullcalendar.io

When I want to resize a event, but does it do nothing. I have tried this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventResize. It works in the demo app: https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

```
 calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
    weekends: false,
    events: this.convertBookingProjectsToEvents(),
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
  };

eventResize(info) {
    alert(info.event.title + ' end is now ' + info.event.end.toISOString());

    if (!confirm('is this okay?')) {
      info.revert();
    }
  }
```

How can I make this work?

Kind regards

Comment: You can get to the demo here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing-demo - then click on the "Edit in CodePen" link to find the source code. Maybe worth comparing it to yours and see if anything significant is different in the options.

Comment: P.S. I don't know anything about Angular specifically but I embedded your eventResize callback into a standard fullCalendar setup and it works fine. https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRoGopK . There's no reason to think it wouldn't work in your version assuming you set the option correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the CodePens! I have copy-paste it but I still can not resize it.. When I set 'editable: true', the drag and drops work so it's weird that the resizing part is not functioning in my app

Comment: hard to know without seeing a live demo to be honest. Can you make a CodeSandbox example which reproduces the issue? I think there's a template in fullCalendar Angular documentation. And, do you have any Console errors when you try to resize?

Comment: Hi, so in my app it does not work in the monthView. I see now that it does works in the weekView so I will go with that. But thanks for searching!

Comment: That's pretty odd, there's really no obvious reason it shouldn't. But I can't really tell what's going on without a reproducible example. It ought to be fixable though. Anyway it sounds like you've at least got something which works for you, for now.

Comment: Same for me (Angular 12).  I can drag an event in month view but not resize it.